# Java Spark map step returning multiple RDDs

Tags: java, dictionary, apache-spark, rdd

I have a map step which computes an RDD I need. While computing the data for that RDD another metric can be computed which I am interested in. Is there any way to do both in one step, or do I have to make a separate map which does almost the same thing as the first one ?

Thanks !

Comment: "... another metric can be computed ..." - if you can be more specific (code example) you might get better answers. For example, if this metric is something aggregative (e.g. count of all records matching X), you can use Spark's [Accumulators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators-a-nameaccumlinka) to get that as a "side-effect" of the mapping you're doing anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, however keeping each "map step" simple will lead to more readable code.

Keep in mind that your `map()` is not executed until a terminating function is called, therefore it doesn't matter from a performance point of view whether you do this in one `map()` or two successive `map().map()` calls

*...assuming you don't have to consider data shuffling implications*

Comment: Okay that sounds like I can make the two map steps, but to clear it up, can you point to how multiple RDDs can be returned from one map ? @Brad

Comment: `RDD.map().map()` will still only return one RDD (it's a pipeline of commands leading to a single output). What I interpret from your question is that the returned RDD will contain elements that hold the values of two metrics that you have calculated. So the second call to map builds on the output from the first call to map.